# How to make the property of one array property of another (code optimization)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

That's what I have

```
const users = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Mike', postIds: [11, 22] },
    { id: 2, name: 'Dan', postIds: [33] },
    { id: 3, name: 'Lance', postIds: [44] },
];

const posts = [
    { id: 11, title: 'How good is he' },
    { id: 22, title: 'How fast is he' },
    { id: 33, title: 'How to make it faster' },
    { id: 44, title: 'How can he do it' },
];
```

That's what I need to get in the output

```
const expectedResult = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Mike',
    posts: [
      { id: 11, title: 'How good is he' },
      { id: 22, title: 'How fast is he' },
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Dan',
    posts: [{ id: 33, title: 'How to make it faster' }]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Lance',
    posts: [{ id: 44, title: 'How can he do it' }]
  },
]
```

That's what I tried. It works, but it's stupid and I think it can be done in one operation. Please check what can I do make to it cleaner

```js
const users = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Mike', postIds: [11, 22] },
    { id: 2, name: 'Dan', postIds: [33] },
    { id: 3, name: 'Lance', postIds: [44] },
];

const posts = [
    { id: 11, title: 'How good is he' },
    { id: 22, title: 'How fast is he' },
    { id: 33, title: 'How to make it faster' },
    { id: 44, title: 'How can he do it' },
];

let updUsers = users.map(obj => ({ ...obj,
  posts: [...posts]
}))
const output = updUsers.map(
  user => ({
    ...user,
    posts: user.posts.filter(
      post => user.postIds.includes(post.id)
    )
  })
);
const expectedOut = output.map(({
  id,
  name,
  posts
}) => ({
  id,
  name,
  posts
}))
console.log(expOut)
```

Answer (score 2):

Turn the posts array into a mapping of post ID -> post object for faster lookup:

```
const postMap = new Map(posts.map((p) => [p.id, p]));

const expectedResult = users.map((u) => {
  const newU = { ...u, posts: u.postIds.map((id) => postMap.get(id)) };
  delete newU.postIds;  // Remove the undesired `postIds` property from the copy
  return newU;
});

console.log(expectedResult);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can filter `posts` when you're mapping `users` rather than doing it as a second pass.

```js
const users = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Mike', postIds: [11, 22] },
    { id: 2, name: 'Dan', postIds: [33] },
    { id: 3, name: 'Lance', postIds: [44] },
];

const posts = [
    { id: 11, title: 'How good is he' },
    { id: 22, title: 'How fast is he' },
    { id: 33, title: 'How to make it faster' },
    { id: 44, title: 'How can he do it' },
];

let expOut = users.map(({id, name, postIds}) => ({ id, name,
  posts: posts.filter(({id}) => postIds.includes(id))
}))

console.log(expOut)
```

Comment: OP's post has this exact pattern.

Comment: he did it in two calls to `map`, and asked how to do it in one pass.

Comment: @Barmar sir, do you know where can I find some "alike" tasks? Want to practice in this more

Answer (score 2):

- This is another naive method but time complexity is more.
- P.S.: Time complexity is n^3

```js
const users = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Mike', postIds: [11, 22] },
    { id: 2, name: 'Dan', postIds: [33] },
    { id: 3, name: 'Lance', postIds: [44] },
];

const posts = [
    { id: 11, title: 'How good is he' },
    { id: 22, title: 'How fast is he' },
    { id: 33, title: 'How to make it faster' },
    { id: 44, title: 'How can he do it' },
];

let updUsers = users.map(function(obj){
    let postsArr = [];
    for(i=0; i<obj.postIds.length; i++){
        const postArr = posts.find((item) => item.id == obj.postIds[i]);
        postsArr.push(postArr);
    };


    return{'id':obj.id,'name':obj.name,'posts':postsArr};});

console.log(updUsers);
```

Comment: sir, do you know where can I find some "alike" tasks? Want to practice in this more

Comment: Leetcode.com and Freecodecamp.org are good platforms for enhancing your practice knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

You can first convert your posts array to key value pairs and take object using `Object.fromEntries`, now just map it. Here is an implementation:

```js
const users = [ { id: 1, name: 'Mike', postIds: [11, 22] }, { id: 2, name: 'Dan', postIds: [33] }, { id: 3, name: 'Lance', postIds: [44] },];

const posts = [ { id: 11, title: 'How good is he' }, { id: 22, title: 'How fast is he' }, { id: 33, title: 'How to make it faster' }, { id: 44, title: 'How can he do it' },];

//convert posts to object and then map it:

const postObjects = Object.fromEntries(posts.map(p=>[p.id, p]));

const result = users.map(({id, name, postIds})=>({id, name, posts:postIds.map(p=>postObjects[p])}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: sir, do you know where can I find some "alike" tasks? Want to practice in this more

Answer (score 1):

We can simplify this using `Array.prototype.reduce` and `Array.prototype..filter` and use a `Set` for finding the right posts for a user for faster lookup:

```js
const users = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Mike', postIds: [11, 22] },
    { id: 2, name: 'Dan', postIds: [33] },
    { id: 3, name: 'Lance', postIds: [44] },
];

const posts = [
    { id: 11, title: 'How good is he' },
    { id: 22, title: 'How fast is he' },
    { id: 33, title: 'How to make it faster' },
    { id: 44, title: 'How can he do it' },
];

const mapUsersByPost = (users, posts) => {
  return users.reduce((acc, {id, name, postIds}) => {
   const filteredPosts = posts.filter(({id}) => new Set(postIds).has(id));
   acc.push({ id, name, posts: filteredPosts});
   return acc;
  }, []);
}

console.log(mapUsersByPost(users, posts));
```

Comment: sir, do you know where can I find some "alike" tasks? Want to practice in this more